# Переключение раскладки в LXDE: не работает автостарт через /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart

Tags: linux, автозапуск, lxde

Имеем Debian 8.5 с LXDE 0.7.2

Мне нужно для всех пользователей настроить две раскладки клавиатуры - en+ru, и переключение между ними по ctrl+shift. Для этого я прописываю в файл **/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart** следующую строку:

```
@setxkbmap -option grp:switch,grp:ctrl_shift_toggle us,ru
```

Перезагружаюсь, и никаких настроек переключения клавиатуры не получаю: есть только один английский язык, переключение по клавишам ctrl+shift не работает. Запустил LXTerminal, и от пользователя выполнил эту же команду. Переключение заработало. То есть, по какой-то причине команда настройки не сработала или сработала не в тот момент.

Тогда я попробовал дописать в этот же файл команду:

```
@echo "Hello" > /tmp/hello.txt
```

Перегрузился, захожу в LXDE, а файла **/tmp/hello.txt** не появилось.

Отсюда делаю вывод, что автозапуск команд не работает вообще.

**Вопрос 1:** как же сделать в LXDE автозапуск команд для всех пользователей?

**Вопрос 2:** как настроить в LXDE переключение раскладки клавиатуры более простыми средствами? Пусть и для каждого пользователя, но визуально. В настроечной панели есть добавление раскладок, но это действие неактивно:

http://i.piccy.info/i9/2f0faf32be959b1d1685e5ea49291b2c/1467290104/69464/1047131/keyboard_lxde_01.png

И как сделать активным - непонятно.

Comment: создайте файл в */etc/X11/Xsession.d/*. номер в начале имени помогает расставить порядок вызова. начните имя файла с `99`, дальше произвольное название. выполняются (точнее, подключаются командой `source`) эти файлы от имени пользователя, запускающего x-сессию.

Comment: *@echo "Hello" > /tmp/hello.txt* — возможно, синтаксис оболочки там не поддерживается. замените это на вызов скрипта `@/путь/к/скрипту`, а в нём уже напишите `echo "Hello" > /tmp/hello.txt`, и добавьте биты исполнимости: `chmod +x /путь/к/скрипту`

Answer (score 1):

Утилита для переключения раскладки является виджетом для lxpanel. Она не использует трей. Не забудьте передать управление раскладками утилите при её настройке (в верхнем-правом углу её GUI, насколько я помню). Сам долгое время использовал LXDE.

Comment: вопрос-то был про глобальную настройку, для всех пользователей сразу.

Comment: По идее (не проверялось), можно скопировать нужный конфиг (lxpanel хранит данные в конфигах) в /etc/skel/. Тогда он будет использоваться в качестве стандартного у всех новых пользователей